# how to get multiple react buttons text by one command

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple buttons in a form and I know that I can use below commands for each of the buttons to get text value but its not nice and clean to have repeated code, I wonder if there is another way to have one variable and one function to get all button's text value.

Thanks in advance.

```
btnRef1 = React.createRef();
btnRef2 = React.createRef();
btnRef3 = React.createRef();

getTextValue1 = () => {
    console.log("getTextValue=> char: ", this.btnRef1.current.textContent);
};
getTextValue2 = () => {
    console.log("getTextValue=> char: ", this.btnRef2.current.textContent);
};
getTextValue]3 = () => {
    console.log("getTextValue=> char: ", this.btnRef3.current.textContent);
};

<MDBBtn innerRef={this.btnRef1} onClick={this.getTextValue1}>
    1
</MDBBtn>
<MDBBtn innerRef={this.btnRef2} onClick={this.getTextValue2}>
    2
</MDBBtn>
<MDBBtn innerRef={this.btnRef3} onClick={this.getTextValue3}>
    3
</MDBBtn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need pass text to the function, you can do next:

```
getTextValue = (value) => {
    console.log("getTextValue=> char: ", value);
};

<MDBBtn onClick={() => this.getTextValue(1)}>1</MDBBtn>
```

Also you can use loop for buttons:

```
const buttons = [1,2,3];

buttons.map(value => <MDBBtn onClick={() => this.getTextValue(value)}>{value}</MDBBtn>)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use an arrow function.

```
<MDBBtn innerRef={this.btnRef1} onClick={()=>this.buttonClicked(1)}>
1
</MDBBtn>
```

You can simply pass the value you want to log inside the function call.

This method is simple and works but, there are some performance issues you might want to note. You can read them up in here: https://medium.com/@oleg008/arrow-functions-in-react-f782d11460b4